# Extract values from a json enclosed between [[ ]] array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

Can someone help me extract values from json like below:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "x", 
            "age": "y", 
            "class": "z"
        }
    ]
]
```

I would like to extract `age` from the above json using `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pedestrian way:

```
.[] | .[] | .age
```

The briefer way:

```
.[][].age
```

Another possibility to consider (it has different semantics) would be:

```
 .. | .age?
```